# I am not able to click on link in html anchor tag in bootstrap tooltip

Tags: javascript, html, tooltip

I am using bootstrap tooltip, I have configured a link in tooltip but when I am clicking on that link it is not redirecting to that page, after trying more than 10 time it is redirecting to that particular page.

however on hover it is always showing me the link, but on clicking it is working some time and sometime not.

code :

```
<span class="btn-sm pull-right"  data-toggle="tooltip">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="tooltip" data- 
             html="true" title="Print feature is enabled for subscription users.
      <a href='https://www.google.com'>Sign up Today</a>"> 
       Print Result Summary
   </button>
 </span>
```

Comment: are you using any javascript to focusing on the tooltip? Its disappearing as soon as you loose focus from button

Comment: No I am not using any external java script when we click on button tooltip  is not disappearing , but when we click on link in tooltip it is disappearing

Answer (score 0):

Run the below code.

```js
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({'delay':{'hide': 2000}});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
<span class="btn-sm pull-right"  data-toggle="tooltip">
   <button type="button" data-html="true"  class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="tooltip"
     title="Print feature is enabled for subscription users.
  <a href='https://www.google.com'>Sign up Today</a>"> 
       Print Result Summary
   </button>
 </span>
```

Comment: Nope it is not working on clicking it is not redirecting

Comment: it is hitting Link once in 20 times

Comment: Once run the code snippet now. You need to add delay for the tooltip to show it for some time.

Comment: when I am adding delay then my tooltip is not even working

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this and tried it as well on my project

- by default all events are reset on container
- events are triggered from the one level not bubbled
- tooltip is created "on the fly", so your jQuery has reference to object which does not exist.
- mixing SVG / HTML elements does not allow you to use CSS pointer-events
  properly.

Workaround:

- apply pointer-events: 'auto' or run click event action inline.

reference: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/9986